# Error when connecting the Slack app to my dev Salesforce org

Tags: slack, slack-salesforce-app

I've just created a Slack channel as a test for myself and I wanted to add the Salesforce to Slack integration by linking Slack to my dev org.

However, when I click on 'Allow' to add the integration, I get this error message.
What can I do about it? Anyway to fix it? Is it because I'm connecting Slack to a dev org?

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what is the correct solution for this problem, but in my case, I was getting this error as well in chrome and I tried with edge and it worked, I think you could try with another browser.

Comment: Changing the browser you use should not really make a difference here. Even if it would, for this discussion Chrome and Edge are functionally the same browser (they both use Google's "Chromium" at time of writing). The problem is that there's too much data in the headers of some HTTP request (and the headers should be pretty much identical across browsers). Which request? Which side is complaining? The question unfortunately doesn't tell us (it'd have been nice if the question included the request headers from the browser's developer tools).

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, but it does. I tested this again, and when I use Chrome, I get an error, but not when I use Edge. However, using a different browser is not a solution but rather a workaround.

Comment: Reproducing the error, and showing us the request headers (with any sensitive information removed, obviously) for the two browsers would go a lot further in helping people get to the root cause.